# aws cli のように s3 のパスを / 区切りでリストしたい

Tags: ruby, aws, amazon-s3, aws-cli

[RubyでAWS S3のオブジェクトの一覧を取得してみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/b_a_a_d_o/items/a38987c6cb4bccfe2834)

こちらを参考に s3 のバケットのリスティングはできたのですが
プレフィックス以下のすべてのオブジェクトが表示されてしまいます

S3の / はディレクトリではなく単なるパスなので当然ではあるんですが

```
bucket/aaa/111
          /222
      /bbb/333
          /444
```

という構成になってるときに aws cli で

```
aws s3 ls bucket
```

とうったときのように aaa bbb だけ表示したいです

自分で全部のリストから最初の / までを取得して重複を除去するみたいな処理を書くしかないですか？
そういうことをやってくれるライブラリみたいなのがあったりしないでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`delimiter`オプションに`/`を指定](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#list_objects_v2-instance_method)してはどうでしょうか？

Comment: んー　すみません使い方がよくわからなかったです。　delimiter: '/' を追加すると１つもHITしなくなります。prefix や max_keys を消してみたり prefix の最後を / にしたりしなかったりしても１つもHITしません

Comment: すみません　res.contents.map(&:key) ではなく　res.common_prefixes.map(&:prefix)　に入ってたみたいです　取得できました